# IIS Traffic breakdown by Application

Tags: logging, iis, traffic

I have an legacy IIS web server with 28 applications under the "Default Web Site" site. I'm trying to get a breakdown of traffic to these applications to see which ones are still being hit on a regular basis.

I've inherited this server so I'm not really familiar with how the sites were setup. I've tried to use Log Parser to get the top pages by the number of hits in the logs, but it's still not really giving me what I want.

Given the following setup:

- Default Web Site

  - App 1
  - App 2
  - App 3

I'd like to see a breakdown that says over the a given time frame:

- App 1 : 20 hits
- App 2 : 100 hits
- App 3 : 45 hits

Does anything like this exist or anyone have suggestions for it?

Thanks

Comment: Import IIS log files to a database like SQL Server, and there you can compose complex SQL queries to reveal those data you want (merge URLs for each applications first). Too broad to discuss the details, but you get the ideas.

Comment: What is the purpose of obtaining the number of hits for each App? Is it to prevent the app from being frequently accessed? If this is the case, then you can set it in iis ip address and domain restrictions.

Comment: @samwu the idea is to see which apps are still being accessed to see if they need to be migrated to a new server.

Comment: You can check the apps in the iis log or you can use Process Monitor to see request total.